# Making apache camel listen to a port and load balnce the request to other URI's

Tags: port, load-balancing, apache-camel, host

I have a code here which is a example code from camel's official website:

```
package org.apache.camel.processor;

import org.apache.camel.AsyncCallback;
import org.apache.camel.ContextTestSupport;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerSupport;

public class CustomLoadBalanceTest extends ContextTestSupport {
    protected MockEndpoint x;
    protected MockEndpoint y;
    protected MockEndpoint z;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        x = getMockEndpoint("mock:x");
        y = getMockEndpoint("mock:y");
        z = getMockEndpoint("mock:z");
    }

    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                // START SNIPPET: e1
                from("direct:start")
                    // using our custom load balancer
                    .loadBalance(new MyLoadBalancer())
                    .to("mock:x", "mock:y", "mock:z");
                // END SNIPPET: e1
            }
        };
    }

    public void testCustomLoadBalancer() throws Exception {
        x.expectedBodiesReceived("x", "x", "x");
        y.expectedBodiesReceived("y", "y");
        z.expectedBodiesReceived("foo", "bar", "baz");

        template.sendBody("direct:start", "x");
        template.sendBody("direct:start", "y");
        template.sendBody("direct:start", "foo");
        template.sendBody("direct:start", "bar");
        template.sendBody("direct:start", "y");
        template.sendBody("direct:start", "x");
        template.sendBody("direct:start", "x");
        template.sendBody("direct:start", "baz");

        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }

    // START SNIPPET: e2
    public static class MyLoadBalancer extends LoadBalancerSupport {

        public boolean process(Exchange exchange, AsyncCallback callback) {
            String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
            try {
                if ("x".equals(body)) {
                    getProcessors().get(0).process(exchange);
                } else if ("y".equals(body)) {
                    getProcessors().get(1).process(exchange);
                } else {
                    getProcessors().get(2).process(exchange);
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                exchange.setException(e);
            }
            callback.done(true);
            return true;
        }
    }
    // END SNIPPET: e2

}
```

This code is for performing a custom load balance using apache camel.
I want apache camel to listen to local host and to a port and balance the load among servers specified via IPaddress and port no. The server side has tomcat installed and it would listen to the request.

So how can i modify the below code to meet my requirements.
I am kinda new to camel.Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank a ton in advance.
Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's some route code to make the load balancer work
However, I've not checked the internals of your custom load balancing class, but that should be rather straight forward.

```
from("jetty://http://0.0.0.0:8080/test")
  .loadBalance(new MyLoadBalancer())
  .to("http://tcserver1:8080/hello","http://tcpserver2:8080/hello","http://tcpserver3:8080/hello");
```

Comment: If i am not sure, i would have to install jetty in the load balancing system, which would pass the request to camel. If it is the case, then is there any other way i could configure camel in a way that it itself acts as a TCP port listener? if not is there any other options that is left for me?

Comment: Actually, Camel fires up a tiny jetty instance that creates the HTTP listener, so the listener would be on HTTP level. You don't have do anything but provide dependencies. You could probably do this using a more raw TCP listener (look at the mina or netty component in camel) but then it will be a bit tricky, since you need to be able to parse the TCP stream and extract each HTTP request. If you are still interessted, look here: http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/xref/org/apache/mina/example/httpserver/codec/  

I would go with Camel/Jetty, it will be no "installing" except your camel app.